# finding substring in python from MySQL research

Tags: python, mysql, substring

First of all, i'm searching a way to implement every character in a tuples, and then add those number.

right now, my codes looks like this :

```
def separate(s):
    result = [0, 0]
    for c in s:
        if c == "0":
            result[0] = result[0] + 1
        elif c == "1":
            result[1] = result[1] + 1
        else:
            raise "invalid sequence."
        return result

s = "01010101101010"

zero, one = separate(s)

print(zero)
print(one)
```

i dont quite understand why the answer it gives me is only the 2nd valor of my s(which is a 1) and 0 for my (one)

My second question is : I'm trying to get a list from MySQL but the column doesnt exist, i made it myself ( so substring(prediction, startpos,endpos-startpos)
I'm asking if there is a way for me to get this substring in my code (instead of the s='101011101';

Thanks. i hope i'm clear enough

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning in every iteration of the for loop (in other words: you are returning in the first iteration). Unindent the "return" line one level.

Comment: Thanks ! And what about my problem to get my substring instead of the s="101011101'?

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking there. What exactly do you have stored in your database that you want to turn into strings like that one? Do you mean to do it in Python or in SQL? I take it you are already capable of retrieving and outputting resultset values from a query you made?

Comment: In my database, i have amino acid that i have to compare to order/disorder (that is 0 and 1).
i am not able to use this column that i created(from those 2 comparisons)
My column that i created is a 'text' format, and i want to get every 0 and 1 in this column and know how much there is to those column.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you already have a column (of type TEXT) in your database table that contains the strings that are of interest. If so, can you not just retrieve values from that column and pass them directly in to the function that you have written? What is the obstruction?

Comment: I think you are having trouble with basic operation of your database library. It sounds like you cannot retrieve values from your database table (I do not think you should be passing the cursor object as the function parameter - the database library probably has a function for fetching a row from the cursor, either as a list or as a dict). You should probably turn to the documentation for the database library, and if you cannot arrive at a solution then post a new question.